# what is the usage of dvb triplet in Settop box?

Tags: dvb

I am seeing that the way to identify the service is through DVB triplet. How DVB triplet is formed, and how it guarantees to be unique?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According `TS 102 539`, a DVB Triplet is composed of:

1. Original Network Id
2. Transport Stream Id
3. Service Id

This triplet is unique and allows to fully identify a service because:

- 2 programs will have different S-ID within a TS
- 2 TS will have different TS-ID within a Network
- Each Network has his unique ON-ID provided by DVB.

Answer (score 3):

Some supplementary information in addition to Coconop's answer, which is basically correct.

TS 102 539 is for IPTV applications.

The canonical references for the triplet in broadcast applications are [EN 300 468](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/300400_300499/300468/01.15.01_60/en_300468v011501p.pdf) and [TS 101 211](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/101200_101299/101211/01.12.01_60/ts_101211v011201p.pdf). In this scenario, it depends on which market the broadcast signal originates from. If TS 101 211 is **not** part of the broadcast profile, then the triplet uniquely identifies a service. If TS 101 211 **is** part of the broadcast profile, then you can leave out the transport stream ID, since in that case the service ID must be unique within an original network ID.

It is thus safe in all cases to use the full triplet to identify a service.

There is also a standard for a `dvb` URL scheme in [TS 102 851](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/102800_102899/102851/01.03.01_60/ts_102851v010301p.pdf), which uses the triplet as part of the URL. AFAIR, the Xine player understands `dvb://` URLs.